# factorsing a quadratic trinomial by completeing the square

Tags: abstract-algebra

Question = **2x^2 + 12x − 1 = 0**

I got an answer = **2(x + 3 + 19/2)(x + 3 - 19/2)**

However, my textbook displays different answer, for instance 
**2(x + 3 + √19/2)(x + 3 - √19/2)**.

The main difference is the (***√19/2***).

I got the answer by following this method: 
 2(x^2 + 6x - 1/2)
**->** 2[(x^2 + 6x + 9) -9 -1/2] 
    **->** 2[(x^2 + 6x + 9) - 19/2] 
   **->** 2[(x+3)^2 - 19/2)] 
    **->** 2[(x+3)^2 - (√19/2)^2, since when squaring a square root its give 19/2, therefore

**-> 2(x + 3 + 19/2) (x + 3 - 19/2).**

Could someone please explain me why the square root is necessary in that equation?

Comment: How did you get your answer?

Comment: Please learn how to format your answers. The first step is to put math between  a pair of $.

Comment: Your error is at the end: $(x+3)^2-(\sqrt{19/2})^2=(x+3-\sqrt{19/2})(x+3-\sqrt{19/2})$ not $(x+3+19/2)(x+3-19/2)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you complete the square here, you get $2 (x^2+6x)-1=2(x+3)^2-1-18=2(x+3)^2-19$.

Now I guess the difference of two squares pattern was used: $a^2-b^2=(a+b)(a-b)$.

Hence $2((x+3)+\sqrt{\dfrac{19}2})((x+3)-\sqrt{\dfrac{19}2})$.

Comment: Originally you have $19/2$ but, then you use that $(\sqrt{19/2})^2=19/2$.